# JPA Saving parent and child on @OneToOne gives the foreign key of the child null

Tags: java, oracle, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I'm using spring data JPA and an Oracle DB. I want to save 2 entities, and they are saved correctly but the child value of the FK that is pointing to the parent is null.

Here's the parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="d_utente")
@Getter
@Setter
public class DUtente implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_d_utente")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idDUtente;

    @OneToOne(
            mappedBy = "utente",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private DSoggetto soggetto;
```

And here's the child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="d_soggetto")
@Getter
@Setter
public class DSoggetto implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_d_soggetto")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idDSoggetto;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_d_utente", referencedColumnName = "id_d_utente")
    private DUtente utente;
```

Now, if I do this (where `idDUtente` and `idDSoggetto` are both null):

```
utenteSocio.setSoggetto(soggetto);
utenteRepository.save(utenteSocio);
```

Both soggetto and utente are saved, but `fk_d_utente` on `D_SOGGETTO` is `null`. Is there something wrong in my mapping?
Because if I do what it's written below, all works fine and the correct value of `fk_d_utente` is saved too, but I suppose it's redundant to use `setUtente`(both `idDUtente` and `idDSoggetto` are null too):

```
utenteSocio.setSoggetto(soggetto);
soggetto.setUtente(utenteSocio);
utenteRepository.save(utenteSocio);
```

Comment: With setting the `mappedBy = "utente"` you set the `DSoggetto` as the owning (parent) entity - is this really what you want? You could set the `mappedBy` to the `DSoggetto#utente` and switch the child <> parent relationship. This should solve the `null` FK problem

Comment: @Jelmen I can switch the parent/child relationship, I have no costraints. So I can switch the relationship and saving the `soggetto` instead of the `utenteSocio`, right?

Comment: no you save it the same way

Comment: @Jelmen but I have to modify the database? I will prefer to not modify it. May you explain better your solution in an answer? Thanks!

Comment: yes the proposal includes a datatbase schema change. If it is not possible, you can not change the "owning" entity

Comment: Ok, so if there's no other solution, I suppose I will keep my ugly but working solution.